# Calculating the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n2n(2n-1)}{2^{2n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

The sum of the title is
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nn(2n-1)x^{2n-1}$$
evaluated at $x=\frac{1}{2}$. I have tried to calculate the sum by writing
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nn(2n-1)x^{2n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n2n^2x^{2n-1} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n nx^{2n-1}$$
Now the second addend is easy to compute, but I don't know how to deal with the $n^2$ of the first one. Any tips on how to do it?

Comment: A hint:  consider what happens when you take $(2n)(2n-1)x^{2n}$ and differentiate twice.

Comment: Perhaps not eligant or efficient but I would differentiate or integrate until you get a simple taylor that you recognize or understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nn(2n-1)x^{2n-1}=\frac{x}2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n(2n)(2n-1)x^{2n-2}$$
and note that
$$(x^{2n})''=(2n)(2n-1)x^{2n-2}$$

Can you proceed from here?